# MongoDB map Java POJO without org.bson.types.ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I want to map Java POJO to MongoDB and implement CRUD operations. I follow manual https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/ and all seems fine but one Person property is MongoDB dependent:

```
public final class Person {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;}
```

This is **org.bson.types.ObjectId** id. This makes my domain layer dependent on MongoDB, and this actually what I would not call a POJO at all. **Instead of ObjectId I would like to have String or other Java core class like Long or something like that. It could could be a kind of getter/setter too. How can I achieve this?**

I tried to remove id from Person

```
package com.mongo_demo.domain;
public final class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;}
```

and use this as my domain object, while to operate with MongoDB in DAO I will use child class:

```
package com.mongo_demo.mongo_domain;
public final class Person extends com.mongo_demo.domain.Person {
    private ObjectId id;
}
```

Obviously my domain class now not have dependencies on MongoDB, but still lacks String id and no way to have getter method for it, as ObjectId id attribute is in child class.

I not sure is it fine to not have access to id value in my services code, because I could need to call delete by id operation, otherwise I will have to create my own object unique identifier, in addition to ObjectId id attribute, which will be natural key with consequent drawbacks.

PS No getter-setter methods shown, as I use Lombok @Data annotations instead.